# Sidebar that does't scroll more than its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with long content on it. Together with that there is a sidebar which has less content and at the moment if you continue scrolling down, at some point there will be just whitespace in a sidebar.

So what I tried to do is once sidebar reaches end of its content, height give it fixed position, but while there are still things to scroll give it static position.

So I've got

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    var x = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var s = $('#sidebar').height();
    if (x > s) {
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
                'bottom': '0'
        });
    }
    if (x < s) {
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': 'static'
        });
    }
    });
```

This kinda works. It starts with static position, but when I scroll in any direction it changes to fixed. However I want it to remain static while there is something to scroll through (in upwards and downwards directions)

**EDIT** Basically it should work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cJGVJ/12/ but without the shadow effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give HTML and BODY `height: 100%;`

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```